# Cannot change allow_url_include value in PHP

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I am using `PHP 5.5.9` with `Apache 2.4.7` on my PC running `Ubuntu 14.04`. I am trying to include a PHP script located in another web server just for some testing purposes. But I cannot seem to be able to turn `allow_url_include` on. I tried this:

```
<?php
    echo(ini_get("allow_url_include") . "<br />");

    ini_set("allow_url_include", "On");

    echo(ini_get("allow_url_include"));
?>
```

And it gives me this output:

```
0
0
```

I even tried this by editing the actual `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file and set `allow_url_include = Off`, but still, it's the same.

How do I do it?

Comment: Try to restart apache (or webserver instance whatever)

Comment: Yes, I did it after changing the php.ini file using `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` . Apache restarted, but allow_url_include still seems to be unchangeable.

Comment: Also make sure this is on: `allow_url_fopen =1`

Comment: search in php.ini for allow_url_include for duplicate.

Comment: From my php.ini file: `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: Nope, there are no duplicates of allow_url_include.

Comment: I answered your questions, and it works my server, i hope it works.

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php with: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php Also to make sure your ini file is correct look if you get false: `$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
print_r($ini_array);`

Comment: @Rizier123 I copied the php.ini file to the same directory and ran the code with parse_ini_file(). Interestingly, it gives me this warning: `Warning: syntax error, unexpected '(' in test.ini on line 106` . Line 106 in the ini file has: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: then show us few lines above and under this line of your ini file! That means you have a error in your ini file

Comment: @Rizier123 There are a lot of commented out lines in that section. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/v8HL3NNY

Comment: `error_reporting = E_ALL` not `error_reporting(E_ALL)` - thus, the warning. `error_reporting(E_ALL)` <= is when you put it in a `.php` file. I.e.: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - do that, restart and you should be good to go ;-)

Comment: YES! It worked :D Right, that one line of warning caused it! I changed it to `error_reporting = E_ALL` in the original `php.ini` file and now I can change `allow_url_fopen` to 1. Post it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @lonekingc4 Great, glad to hear it. I've posted my answer, *cheers* and you're quite welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> YES! It worked :D Right, that one line of warning caused it! I changed it to error_reporting = E_ALL in the original php.ini file and now I can change allow_url_fopen to 1. Post it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks everyone. –  lonekingc4

---

I saw your pastebin file with the codes you were using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Use:

`error_reporting = E_ALL` and not `error_reporting(E_ALL)` - thus, the warning

`Warning: syntax error, unexpected '('...`

`error_reporting(E_ALL)`  is used when you put it in a .php file.

I.e.:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of code
```

- Do that, restart Apache and you should be good to go.

**Sidenote:** [**Error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('safe_mode', false);
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
ini_set('allow_url_include', true);
print_r(ini_get_all());


ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');
```

Comment: Do I say the output here?

Comment: Nope, it's still like this:
      [allow_url_fopen] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => 1
            [local_value] => 1
            [access] => 4
        )

    [allow_url_include] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => 0
            [local_value] => 0
            [access] => 4
        )

Comment: @lonekingc4 Maybe try to copy the ini file into the current dir

Comment: If you are a local server may check the firewall settings.

Comment: @Rizier123 I copied php.ini in the same directory where the script is. It's the same thing again.

Comment: @EngineerCoder I turned off my firewall, restarted Apache, and tried this again. But same thing :( No, the php.ini is the correct file as I changed `display_errors: Off` and it hid the errors.

Comment: @lonekingc4 As stated in comments above. Restart Apache and other related services. Changes made to `.ini` files won't take effect; if you haven't already. Edit: Just saw your comment; scratch that.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because it is NOT reading your php.ini

I had the same issue trying to change php.ini on windows to no avail. You must find the correct default location:

Create a test.php file and add phpinfo(); 
Open the file in the browser and check for the following values:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   C:\WINDOWS\php.ini

When you move your php.ini file to the right location and restart php server the changes will finally take effect.

Enjoy!